# WordPress: CODE to define column width for single row of table

Tags: html, wordpress

WordPress: Seeking a way to change column widths and concatenate columns on individual rows in a WordPress table w/ HTML.
Example: https://synergycbd.com/catalog/

Tried:

```
<table style="height: 404px;" width="635">
<tbody>
<tr width="635"><strong><em>ACDC ~ The ultimate CBD medicine:</em></strong>
<div style="font-size: .95rem; line-height: .95rem;">
<td>This strain...
```

and

```
<table style="height: 404px;" width="635">
<tbody>
<tr><strong><em>ACDC ~ The ultimate CBD medicine:</em></strong>
<div style="font-size: .95rem; line-height: .95rem;">
<td  width="635">This strain...
```

'Would like this row to appear in one column in the table and to be the full width of the table.  Other rows to contain multiple columns of defined widths.

Many Thanks ~:~ Jacob

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Remove designated row from table altogether.  Took a few minutes.  MANY THANKS!